# POST request not completing on postman

Tags: node.js, hapi.js, hapi

The route with GET method works but the route with the POST method doesn't work. The postman is keep running and doesn't respond with a response.

Here is what I have tried,

```js
import * as hapi from "@hapi/hapi";
const init = async () => {
    const server: hapi.Server = new hapi.Server({
        port: 3000,
        host: 'localhost'
    });

   server.route({
        method: 'POST', // if you change it to GET, it works
        path: '/test',
        handler: function (request, h) {
            const payload = { username: 'testUserNames'};
            return payload.username;
        }
    });

    await server.start();
    console.log('Server running on %s', server.info.uri);

}

process.on('unhandledRejection', (err) => {
    console.log(err);
    process.exit(1);
});

init();
```

What could be the issue? where am I wrong?

Answer (score 5):

i had the same problem and i solved it by downgrading to node v14. for some reason the hapi framework isn't compatible with node v16.

Comment: Thank you for sharing your feedback. I'd downgrade and check if this is the isue.

Comment: In my case, I created a new hapi project, and test it out, It worked. But  post method doesn't work in the same project.

Comment: Downgrading from v16 to v14 also worked for me.

Comment: There's some more information about why this was happening in this GitHub comment on the hapi repo: https://github.com/hapijs/hapi/issues/4298#issuecomment-939193748